# Unable to append data into Azure storage using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the below code to append data to Azure blob using python.

```
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService
append_blob_service = AppendBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

# The same containers can hold all types of blobs
append_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer')

# Append blobs must be created before they are appended to
append_blob_service.create_blob('mycontainer', 'myappendblob')
append_blob_service.append_blob_from_text('mycontainer', 'myappendblob', u'Hello, world!')

append_blob = append_blob_service.get_blob_to_text('mycontainer', 'myappendblob')
```

The above code works fine, but when I tried to insert new data, the old data gets overwritten.
Is there any way I can append data to 'myappendblob'

Comment: Are you calling the same code every time you try to append contents to the blob?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, same code with different data to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are calling the same code to append the data, the issue is with the following line of code:

```
append_blob_service.create_blob('mycontainer', 'myappendblob')
```

If you read the documentation for [`create_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.appendblobservice.appendblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#azure-storage-blob-appendblobservice-appendblobservice-create-blob) method, you will notice the following:

> **Creates a blob or overrides an existing blob**. Use if_none_match=* to
> prevent overriding an existing blob.

So essentially you are overriding the blob every time you call your code.

You should call this method with `if_none_match="*"` as the documentation suggests. If the blob exists, your code will throw an exception which you will need to handle.

Comment: append_blob_service.create_blob('raw', 'appendblob2',if_none_match=*) it give me invalid syntax. Kindly let me know what im missing here. Thank you

Comment: Try `append_blob_service.create_blob('raw', 'appendblob2',if_none_match="*")` (essentially put `*` in double quotes).

Comment: Thank you it worked. Is there any way we can load the data to a table from Python.

Comment: `Is there any way we can load the data to a table from Python` - Please ask a separate question for this and provide all the details there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which is taken from the [Document](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-append-data-in-blob-storage-in-azure-using-python) and it is given by @Harsh Jain ,

```
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService
   def append_data_to_blob(data):
     service = AppendBlobService(account_name="<Storage acc name>",

       account_key="<Storage acc key>")

     try:

       service.append_blob_from_text(container_name="<name of Conatiner >", blob_name="<The name of file>", text = data)

     except:

       service.create_blob(container_name="<name of Conatiner >", blob_name="<the name of file>")

       service.append_blob_from_text(container_name="<name of Conatiner>", blob_name="<the name of file>", text = data)

     print('Data got Appended ')

 append_data_to_blob('Hi blob')
```

***Taken References from:***

https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-append-data-in-blob-storage-in-azure-using-python